# How to get a jQuery validate error to appear over an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I am working with a jQuery validation plugin and the errors are displaying in a block form, which is fine, but I am wanting the error messages to appear over-top of the input in which the validation is specifying needs correction.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

I have tried to specify the `margin-top`, by making it 0. I have also tried to make `vertical-align: top;`.

I am including a jsfiddle in a comment below in order to demonstrate this with the external plugin.

Does anyone see what I can do?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wgtLnxfw/6/#&togetherjs=eu12IPDNO8

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use any plugin for that.just need `jquery`.I have created a sample for the first field(name), you can do others like this and can change your style.look at this.hope this will help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
 .errormessageOne{
    display: none;
    color: red;
 }  

</style>


</head>
<body>

<div class="fieldOne">
    <h3 class="errormessageOne">please enter your name here</h3>
    <input type="text" id="name"/>
</div>

<div class="submit">
    <button id="send">submit</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#send").click(function(){
        if ($("#name").val()=="" || $("#name").val()== null)
         {
            $(".errormessageOne").show(500);
         };
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```